# Telebot нужно создать условие

Tags: python, telebot, pycharm

Всем привет, пишу бота помощника, для подготовки к ЕГЭ. Программирую не так давно, вот и возник вопрос: как считать время простоя?
То есть, если бот не видит ответа на вопрос в течение 30-50 сек, нужно прислать человеку что-то на подобии "Ало, ты тут?"
На заранее спасибо)

Comment: например используя таймер https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-timer-modulja-threading/

Comment: Вы пользуетесь вебхуками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать модуль threading.

Вот пример:

```
from telebot import *
import threading as thr

bot = TeleBot("token")


def time_reply(s):
    def worker():
        time.sleep(s)
        bot.send_message("chat id", "Ты еще тут?")

    a = thr.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
    a.start()


time_reply(50)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Боюсь ваше решение наспамит кучу сообщений через 50 секунд вне зависимости от того, были ответы, или нет

Comment: Я показал только пример функции 'time_reply()'. А её можно использовать как угодно.